# \tcbset behaves differently in preamble and main body

Tags: tcolorbox

I tried disabling the automatic starting of a new paragraph after a `tcblisting` or `tcolorbox` environment (from the `tcolorbox` package) by using `\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}`.
If I put this code in the main body of the document then I get the desired result:

[image: Expected output]

But if I put it in the preamble (where I think it ought to be) then I get something broken instead:

[image: Unexpected output.]

(The box seems to become part of the previous line.)
This problem does not seem to occur with some other options, e.g. `\tcbset{colback=yellow}` gives the same result in both positions.

Is this behavior intended?
If so, how can the option `after={\par\noindent}` be set globally in the preamble?

The used code for the unexpected output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}

\begin{document}
%\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}

Before the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  The box.
\end{tcolorbox}
After the box.

\end{document}
```

**PS:** I tried the above code with different compilers (LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX) on both my local machine and on Overleaf, and got the above situation each time.

Comment: I see no difference, and why should the `after` key change the behaviour *before* the tcolorbox?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The problem can be replicated on Overleaf, so I guess that it is not just my local machine. I don’t know why `after` would change the behavior before the tcolorbox, or if this really is what is happening.

Comment: overleaf uses an quite outdated texsystem. How current is your local system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I *can* reproduce the issue with a current TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg can you sent me a log?

Comment: @egreg Ah, I just understood  what is meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default tcolorbox uses the `autoparskip`. This option sets *at the begin of the document* the `before` and `after` keys to values sensible in dependance of the current value of `\parskip`.

If you are changing `after` in the preamble you are disabling `autoparskip`. In this case you have to set `before` yourself.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{before={\par\pagebreak[0]\smallskip\parindent=0pt},after={\par\noindent}}

\begin{document}


Before the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  The box.
\end{tcolorbox}
After the box.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the preamble, use `\AtBeginDocument{\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}}

\begin{document}
%\tcbset{after={\par\noindent}}

Before the box.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  The box.
\end{tcolorbox}
After the box.

\end{document}
```

[image]